# Difference between ささぐ and ささげる

Tags: words

beginner Japanese language self-learner here. I hope my question isn't a bad question.

As title suggested, I would like to know about the difference between the two verbs which I understood have the same dictionary meaning, "to dedicate." However, beyond the fact that ささぐ is a 五段 verb and ささげる is an 一段 verb, I really have no idea how/when to use which.

Thank you,

Comment: The dictionaries on Yahoo ([大辞泉](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0na&p=%E3%81%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B)・[大辞林](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E3%81%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B)) seem to say that ささぐ is a literary (文語) form of ささげる, so I imagine they have the same meaning.  They also say ささぐ is a 下二段 verb rather than a 五段 verb.  Since you say you're a beginner, perhaps you can stick to ささげる and ignore the literary form?

Comment: here's a context: I found ささぐ from a song, 「君にささぐ」which even I could guess the meaning. But then, as I practiced my reading with a book, I found 「おとなにささげる」and that led me to wonder what is the difference between the two. Also, the verb classifications I mentioned above is from imiwa, a Japanese dictionary (among others) app for iOS.

Comment: Ah, I bet it uses edict.  It looks like edict says ささぐ is a 五段 verb.

Comment: so, to sum it up, I could use ささげる to convey the meaning of "to dedicate" in most, if not all cases? Anyway, if you could give a sample sentence for each word and probably give the simple nuance explanation on each that would be awesome :)

Comment: Yet another victim of the wrong information in EDICT….  As snailplane said, ささぐ is a 下二段 verb in Classical Japanese, not a 五段 verb.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5506/78

Comment: @snailplane: It looks like you have the answer to the question.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for all to point out the flaw in edict dictionary.

Comment: @JesseGood I don't feel comfortable answering.  They asked "if you could give a sample sentence for each word and probably give the simple nuance explanation on each".  I haven't studied Classical Japanese and I don't know what "nuance" it would have if you used the literary form.  (It would "sound literary", I guess?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is exactly the same, but you'll only see ささぐ used in old/formal written text or in lyrics where the number of syllables matter a lot.

For all the other uses, stick to ささげる.

Comment: ah, "where the number of syllables matter a lot," makes it a lot clearer. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't very clear, but "number of syllables matter a lot" refers to the use in lyrics alone. In written text it can be used without regard to syllables.

For example, in a stele you would see ささぐ more commonly than ささげる