# "Irregular" 命令形 of some verbs

Tags: verbs, classical-japanese, imperatives

Recently I've noticed several verbs where the imperative form is used in a way that is not the "correct" conjugation.

> 1. くれる　→　くれ！　→　The one we're all used to
> 2. つける　→　つけ！　→　An example from my プログレッシブ dictionary:  「気をつけ」と先生が号令をかけた。
> 3. はじめる　→　はじめ！　→　Said often by Master Splinter when the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles have training sessions in [Nickelodeon's newest incarnation of the series](http://www.nick.com/ninja-turtles/).

With #1, I don't know if I've ever learned *why* this is the standard conjugation.  Is it just because it sounds more natural?  With the latter two, I'm assuming that these are acceptable because maybe in 戦前/classical Japanese, はじむ existed as a real word, and つく could be used both as a transitive and intransitive verb; (both) similar to what we discuss [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5506/78) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12837/78).

I have to admit that hearing `はじめ!` in those TMNT episodes sounded completely natural to me, and it didn't even click for a long time that it was not the 命令形 I was expecting.  Even `つけ` sounds very natural when used as a 他動詞.

So I guess my question is, is there a limited set of verbs where the imperative is "different", yet acceptable to use even in modern Japanese?  If my assumption about #2 and #3 is correct, can *any* verb with an "obsolete" form use the imperative conjugation of that form?  What are some other common verbs with different imperative forms like this (if any)?

Comment: くれ seems to have been contracted from くれい/くれよ. I think `noun(+da)` and `o+inf.(+da)` are often used as imperatives, such as, 起立, 突撃, お休み, etc. I think they are more like giving instructions. As for 気がつく/気をつける, I think it's one verb consisting of four/five syllables rather than a verb phrase. For example, we have 気がつかせる. 気をつけ and はじめ are also nouns.

Comment: Looks like the "regular" imperative form くれろ was used until around the Meiji period, and [then disappeared for some reason](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1312760643). I haven't even noticed くれ is irregular...

Comment: Is this just a case of the old (shimo-)nidan meireikei surviving in fossilised expressions in Modern Japanese?

Comment: Perhaps it's sound shift from はじめよ to はじめい to はじめ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## ～くれ

The word, `くれ`, is a special word.
The original form of this is `くれる (呉れる)` and the imperative form is `くれろ`, while it's a deprecated expression.

[According to Daijirin](http://goo.gl/W5FI8z):

> 〔命令形は「くれ」が普通〕
>
> 3. その動作者{どうさしゃ}が話{はな}し手{て}または話題{わだい}の人物{じんぶつ}のために何{なん}らかの動作{どうさ}をすることを表{あらわ}す
>
>    (Translation: [`くれ` is general in imperative form]
>
>    This means that the hearer do thing for speaker or another person.)

Daijirin says that `くれ` is general and it implies that `くれ` is a special case.

[According to Wikipedia](http://goo.gl/i6XVBl):

> ラ行{ぎょう}下一段{しもいちだん}活用{かつよう}に属{ぞく}する「呉（く）れる」は、一般{いっぱん}に命令形{めいれいけい}が「くれ」となる。ただし方言{ほうげん}や古{ふる}い口語{こうご}では「くれろ」となることもある。
>
> (Translation: `くれる` belong to ラ行{ぎょう}下一段{しもいちだん}活用{かつよう} group. Its imperative form is `くれ` generally. But in some dialects or old use, it will be `くれろ` sometimes.)

My impression is that this word has varied in special way like `する` and `来{く}る`.

`する` belong to the unique conjugation called `サ行{ぎょう}変格{へんかく}活用{かつよう}`, and only this word belongs to this conjugation group. Also `来{く}る` belongs `カ行変格活用` in similar way.

Both `する` and `来る` have varied in special way because they are very very old word and are used very often.

## 気をつけ

The example you showed, `気{き}をつけ`, is spoken by captain, leader, teacher and some person like them.  I think `気をつけ` is used like noun because person like teachers use this word like below when they make children stand at attention:

> 気をつけ しよう。
>
> 気をつけの 姿勢{しせい}に なって。
>
> (Both can be translated as: Stand at attention.)

It is interesting that `気をつけろ` doesn't mean `Stand at attention.`; it simply means `Pay attention.`

## はじめ

Person like teachers use this when an exam begins. For example:

> (試験{しけん}、)はじめ！
>
> (Translation: Begin your exam.)

It's similar to `気をつけ` and used widely. We can declare the beginning of something with this, while `気をつけ` means only `Stand at attention.`

> 用意{ようい}、はじめ！
>
> (Translation: Get set, go! / start!)

## Another example: やめ

This and `はじめ` are used together in many cases. It's similar to `気をつけ` and `はじめ` that it's used like a noun.

> 試験、はじめ！ -> やめ！
>
> (Translation: Begin your exam. -> Stop writing.)

## EDIT

In the other words, I wanted to say that:

- `くれ` is a conjugation of `くれる`.
- `つけ` is NOT a conjugation of `つける`; it's a noun. But on `気をつけ`, Japanese includes me feel like whole `気をつけ` constructs one noun. Here is a [reference](http://goo.gl/aML1aD).
- `はじめ` is NOT a conjugation of `はじめる`; it's also a noun. Declaring the beginning of something with this word is a special use.
- `やめ` is NOT a conjugation of `やめる`. Furthermore, `やめ`, `やめろ` and `やむ` are not a conjugation of each other except a few cases (the cases are written below).

  > [やめ](http://goo.gl/pMZir1) = (noun) やめること。中止{ちゅうし}。とりやめ。
  >
  > [やめる](http://goo.gl/irF68o) = (*transitive* verb) 1. 続{つづ}けてきたことを，終{お}わりにする。 2. しようとしていたことを，しないことにする。
  >
  > [やむ](http://goo.gl/XQrFSv) = (*intransitive* verb) 1. それまで続{つづ}いていたことが，切{き}れて続{つづ}かなくなる。 … 〔「止{や}める」に対{たい}する自動詞{じどうし}〕

In old Japanese, `やむ` has a transitive meaning. In modern Japanese, the transitive meaning is no longer available.

Why traffic signs say `とまれ` instead of `やめろ` is that `とまれ` and `やめろ` is a different word (even if they use same Kanji `止`.)

- Basic meanings

  > やめろ (Stop doing that. (To a human))
  >
  > とまれ (Stop moving. (To something moving, not only a human))
  >
  > とめろ (Stop moving something. (To a human))
- Example of above

  > 私は車を運転するのをやめる。 (I stop driving a car.)
  >
  > 車がとまる。 (A car stops.)
  >
  > 私は車をとめる。 (I stop a car.)

Well, I thought it's funny that the sign doesn't ask human to stop his/her car. But any way, the word on traffic sign is `とまれ`.

#### A exception of use of `やめ`

In a few cases, `やめ` is used like a imperative verb. The targets are the nature or some  *awesome* things in most cases.

> 雨{あめ}よ止{や}め！ (Stop raining! (To the nature))
>   木枯{こが}らしよ止{や}め！ (Stop blowing! (To the nature))

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございました。  Thank you for including `やめ`, but is it really an irregular case of `やめろ`, or is it just the normal 命令形 of `やむ`?  I always thought it was the latter, like "Be stopped!" -- similar to how streets and traffic signs say `止まれ` instead of `止めろ`.  Very interesting about the difference between `気をつけ` and `気をつけろ`.

Comment: I added some explanation. Please read the section EDIT.

Comment: If you included the comparison between やむ・とまる and やめる・とめる because you thought I was confused by them, I was not.  I meant that I originally thought `やめ！` was the 命令形 of the 他動詞 `やむ`, just as `止まれ` is the 命令形 of the 他動詞 `止まる` -- I didn't think `やめ` was the noun.

Comment: Analysing つけ as a noun seems… not quite right to me. It may well be that native Japanese speakers (I am not one) think of 気をつけ as a simple noun, but it is clearly in origin a verb and its object. Can nouns take postpositional phrases with を? I can’t think of any way to create a valid phrase/sentence with _NをN_. For example, 「車を運転！」 does not seem like it should be valid to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Short: It won't be interpreted separately like 気 + を + つけ. It's just 気をつけ because it's [連語]{れんご} (collocation, phrase). `気をつけ` (`At attention` in English?) came from army you know, and makes one big noun-like word (連語) that means `at attention`.

Comment: @TakumiSueda But that's not what your answer says—your answer says that つけ is a noun. I have no trouble with 気をつけ as a collocation being seen as a noun, but saying that within that collocation, つけ on its own is also a noun doesn't seem right to me.