# Is くれ the short form for くれる?

Tags: usage, conjugations, imperatives

In the following sentence:

> ペンを貸してくれ。

Is くれ the short form for くれる?

Comment: See also ["Irregular" 命令形 of some verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19131/78).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by short form? Usually that's another name for 辞書形｛じしょけい｝ or the 'dictionary form', which くれる already is in itself. It's not an abbreviation, either; rather くれ is the irregular 命令形｛めいれいけい｝ 'imperative' of くれる. It's a little lighter as a command than 「ペンを貸せ」 would be, but not so much as 貸して or 貸してください