# The path to 楽しみ

Tags: etymology, conjugations, suffixes

In 楽しみにしています, does 楽しみ come from appending the み suffix to 楽しい, or does it come from the 連用形/V-stem/Masu-form of 楽しむ? I.e. Which of the following is it:

> A. 楽しい→楽しみ 
>   B. 楽しむ→楽しみ

Appending the み suffix refers to generating nouns from い-adjectives such as:

- 高い→高み
- 深い→深み
- 明るい→明るみ
- 赤い→赤み
- 暖かい→暖かみ
- 厚い→厚み
- 弱い→弱み
- 強い→強み
- 甘い→甘み
- 苦い→苦み
- おもしろい→おもしろみ

Of note is that process above generates み-nouns from い-adjectives as opposed to being generated from verbs, and is **capable of generating み-nouns from words that do not have a related む-ending verb** (I.e. there is no おもしろむ→おもしろみ).

However, many of the above seem to have a corresponding verb which, **of particular note, contains a *-m-* sound** which could be related to the み suffix generation rule above:

- 高める・高まる
- 深める・深まる
- 赤める
- 暖める・暖まる
- 弱める・弱まる
- 強める・強まる

It then seems that these **may** be possible processes (taking one of the ~める verbs as an example):

[image: mi suffix chart]

In this hypothesis, the verb is the origin. Some unknown mechanism (1)(Verb to Adj) generates a い adjective, and another mechanism (2)(Verb to Noun) generates a み-noun. Following this, a relationship between the adjective and the noun develops (3)(Adj to Noun). Then, this new mechanism (3) is extended to adjectives that do not have a corresponding verb containing a *-m-* sound, which is mechanism (4).

Comparing mechanism (2) to the 終止形 to 連用形 conjugation rule, we note that it is also of a similar type, that is to say that it is a process that is "Verb to Noun". E.g. 笑う→笑い.

---

In another hypothesis, I take the adjective to be the starting point. Where after (1') it gets a む to become [深む](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/191216/meaning/m0u/) (Which may be an old verb form. See: [Rare/Obsolete verb forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5506/542) and [How do 自他 triplets of related verbs work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12837/542)) and then goes on to conjugate normally to 連用形 to get the み ending. As above, the association between the adjective and noun (3') is formed and is extended (4') to adjectives that do not go through (1'):

[image]

This gives me a suspicion that there might exist a verb-like む morpheme hidden in the history of the words that contemporarily do not have an explicit *-m-* sound in order for them to conjugate to a 連用形 containing み such that the processes A and B (right at the beginning of this question) are actually underlyingly the same process.

So restating the question, what is the path to take to get to 楽しみ? Is process A of the nature of (4) in the diagram?

Comment: Can you maybe include more information about this み suffix you mention?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Of note is also that 高み and 深み *may* be "generated" from things like 高む (root of 高まる・高める) and 深む (root of 深まる・深める). So the suffix ～み may be related to the 連用形 of a corresponding verb ending in む.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I have edited it after more thought. The initial question was not well developed.

Comment: Hm... I don't really understand the question now. I would have thought that adjectives (like 深い) are the starting point and that there was an auxiliary verb(?) ～む that attaches to the stem of such adjectives (to give 深む "to deepen"). The meaning of this auxiliary verb would be "to become [adjective]". The 連用形 of this auxiliary verb could now be fossilized as the suffix ～み (with a slightly different meaning).

Comment: @Earthliŋ that means that I might have misidentified the starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Origins

I was recently looking into the etymology of the term 畏{かしこ}まる.  Shogakukan's 国語大辞典 traces this to 畏{かしこ}む, and notes that only the 連用形{れんようけい} is found in the oldest textual appearances.  The entry provides two ancient quotes, one from the 古事記{こじき} and one from the 日本書紀{にほんしょき}, both using the form かしこみて.  It seems possible that this みて ending may represent a stage in the [lexicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicalization) of み, where み derived originally as a conjugated form of the む auxiliary verb, but み then developed uses that are independent of this origin.

む (from which み and also まる and める derive) expresses senses of *appearance* and *seeming*.  I suspect there are two more possible (probable?) cognates here: suppositional む (source of the modern volitional *-ō* ending), and regular verb 見{み}る which some dictionaries list as cognate with 目{ま・め}.

A similar suffix is modern びる, as in terms like 古{ふる}びる and 大人{おとな}びる.  This derives from classical ぶ.  I suspect that this may be a shift from む, as a `/m/` ⇔ `/b/` shift does crop up here and there in Japanese (c.f. the Tama River in western Tokyo, the upper reaches of which are also called the Taba River; also Tōhoku-ben where たびに is rendered as たんびに; and classical verb 浴{あ}む that became modern 浴{あ}びる).

#### Current State

In modern Japanese, the む auxiliary verb has <s>largely disappeared,</s> *been partially* superseded by まる and める as verb-forming suffixes, and み as a noun-forming suffix.  These all come from む, but they are now independent, so you might have a word that can be changed to take one of these endings, but it might not necessarily take the others -- such as 面白い, which can take み but not まる or める.

Looking at your diagrams, I must confess some confusion, so please comment if my post does not answer your question.

Comment: What about 楽しみ? Did it occur after the disappearance of the む auxiliary (I.e. 楽しい→楽しみ was the path taken using み as a noun forming suffix) or did it occur when む was active (I.e. 楽しい→楽しむ→楽しみ).  In modern analysis, do we say it was formed by み as a noun-forming suffix or by verb-conjugation of む?

Comment: @Flaw: Digging around, 楽しむ appears in sources like the 平家物語 from the 1100s, and the 海道記 from 1224.  However, 楽しみ seems to pre-date this, appearing in the 源氏物語 from 1008. This might suggest that み came first. However, 親しむ appears in the 今昔物語 of the early 1100s, while 親しみ appears in the 平治物語 of the late-1100s, early-1200s. Then again, 愛しみ appears in the 古今和歌集 of 913, and 愛しむ appears in the 三宝絵詞 of 1034. Both 慎み and 慎む appear in the 源氏物語.  I can't find any clear evidence of み or む coming first.  Presumably, む came first and み derived from that, but a back-formation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The noun 楽しみ comes from 連用形 of the verb 楽しむ.

For many verbs, their 連用形 can become nouns. For example:

```
手伝う --> 手伝い
親しむ --> 親しみ
返す   --> 返し
調べる --> 調べ
泣く   --> 泣き
```